# How can I have Multiple Yajra Datatables on one page in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

> Problem: I need to use "Product DataTable" in Cash Page
> where "Cash DataTable" already exists on this page.

I've searched for the issue, but I'm surprised no one has asked this before, so when I found a solution for this problem, I decided to share my solution with other programmers. I hope it is useful for you.

Let me first say what versions I work on.

- "laravel/framework": "^8.40"
- "yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons": "^4.0",
- "yajra/laravel-datatables-html": "^4.0",
- "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0"

Now I show my project structures

I have route:list

```
 GET|HEAD | cash | cash.index| App\Http\Controllers\CashController@index
 GET|HEAD | product | product.index| App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@index
```

CashController.php

```
public function index(CashDataTable $cashDataTable)
{

    return $cashDataTable->render('cash.index');
}
```

Cash.index.blade.php

```
{!! $dataTableCash->table(['id'=>'dataTable']) !!}
{!! $dataTableCash->scripts() !!}
```

CashDataTable.php

use App\Models\Cash;

```
class CashDataTable extends DataTable

    public function dataTable($query)
    {
        $dataTable = new EloquentDataTable($query);

        return $dataTable->addColumn('action', 'cash.datatables_actions');
    }
    
    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
            ->columns($this->getColumns())
            ->minifiedAjax()
            ...
    }
    ...
}
```

ProductDataTable.php

```
use App\Models\Product;

class ProductDataTable extends DataTable

    public function dataTable($query)
    {
        $dataTable = new EloquentDataTable($query);

        return $dataTable->addColumn('action', 'product.datatables_actions');
    }
    
    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
            ->columns($this->getColumns())
            ->minifiedAjax()
            ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think "Yajra \ DataTables \ Services;" Designed to show just one table, but I found a solution:

First, we need to override and change the default dataTable variable in CashDataTable and ProductDataTable,
Second, we need to set route URL in HTML minifiedAjax directly.

CashDataTable.php

```
use App\Models\Cash;

protected $dataTableVariable = 'dataTableCash';

class CashDataTable extends DataTable

    public function dataTable($query)
    {
        $dataTable = new EloquentDataTable($query);

        return $dataTable->addColumn('action', 'cash.datatables_actions');
    }
    
    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
            ->columns($this->getColumns())
            ->minifiedAjax('/cash')
            ...
    }
    ...
}
```

ProductDataTable.php

```
use App\Models\Product;

class ProductDataTable extends DataTable

    protected $dataTableVariable = 'dataTableProduct';

    public function dataTable($query)
    {
        $dataTable = new EloquentDataTable($query);

        return $dataTable->addColumn('action', 'product.datatables_actions');
    }
    
    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
            ->columns($this->getColumns())
            ->minifiedAjax('/product')
            ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Now in CashController, we need to set the variable as the HTML builder.

CashController.php

```
public function index(CashDataTable $cashDataTable, ProductDataTable $productDataTable)
{
    $dataTableProduct = $productDataTable->html();

    return $cashDataTable->render('cash.index', compact('dataTableProduct'));
}
```

Cash.index.blade.php

```
{!! $dataTableCash->table(['id'=>'dataTableCash']) !!}
{!! $dataTableCash->scripts() !!}

{!! $dataTableProduct->table(['id'=>'dataTableProduct']) !!}
{!! $dataTableProduct->scripts() !!}
```